# Using Protractor with Yadda framework

Tags: protractor, yadda

I was trying to find some cases of using [Yadda](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yadda) (with Jasmine or some other fw) and [Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor) but with no luck.
Does anybody have experience with it?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I am answering my own question.

Step 1 - define specs for protractor conf file:

```
specs: ['test/yadda-runner.js']
```

Step 2 - create 'test/yadda-runner.js'

```
    var exports = module.exports = {};

exports.runner = (function () {
    var Yadda = require('yadda');
    Yadda.plugins.jasmine.StepLevelPlugin.init();

    new Yadda.FeatureFileSearch('./test/features').each(function foundFeatureFiles(file) {
        featureFile(file, function test(feature) {

            var a = file.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*\.feature/gi)[0],
                name = a.replace(".feature","");

            var definitions = require('./definitions/' + name + '-steps.js');
            var yadda = Yadda.createInstance(definitions);

            scenarios(feature.scenarios, function execute(scenario) {
                steps(scenario.steps, function executeStep(step) {
                    yadda.run(step);
                });
            });
        });
    });
}());
```

Step 3 - Create your feature and step files

"test/features/**bottles**.feature" -> "test/definitions/**bottles**-steps.js"

Comment: I think you forget the done callback. If you don't past it along the next function might not work properly.